# helm push to artifactory always throws 404 error with /api/artifactory/helm/charts not found

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to configure my CI/CL to push the helm chart to artifacotry(JFrog). I am using helm push plugin. But whenever I try to push I always get a response as 404 /api/artifactory/helm/charts not found error.

I have added chartmuseum repo, Installed chartmuseum client and helm-push plugin for helm

This is my Shell script which I call

```
helm repo add chartmuseum http://artifactory.xxxxxxx.com/artifactory/helm
curl -LO https://s3.amazonaws.com/chartmuseum/release/latest/bin/linux/amd64/chartmuseum
chmod +x ./chartmuseum
mv ./chartmuseum /usr/local/bin
echo "Starting Helm-Push Plugin Installation"
helm plugin install https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push
helm push -f mysql/ chartmuseum
```

I get the following response:

```
Error: 404: could not properly parse response JSON: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /api/artifactory/helm/charts was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Error: plugin "push" exited with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chartmuseum is not supported in JFrog. So this failed.